# What is the reason behind use of crackers for temple festivals?

Tags: history, temple, festivals, india

We generally see in temple festivals that use of crackers is a star-attraction. It always attracts a huge crowd. But it may prove fatal too as it is a risk using huge amount of crackers at a time. Do we have a history in the past about use of crackers in temple festivals? Do such activities really please god? Any mention about it in Hindu scriptures?

Comment: This is not a question about Hinduism.

Comment: It is certainly a question about Hinduism. Because temple related things are part of Hinduism. And moreover the question is "does use of crackers is mentioned in scripts too".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because firecrackers is not a very old thing. They were originated around 200 BC in China, so I am not sure if we could really find anything in scriptures related to them.

Comment: It is true that fireworks was invented by the Chinese.However, burning of cracker has become an intergal part of Diwali celebration.Hence, I believe this can not become any off-topic just because there is not mention about them in scriptures.

Comment: This question has a political undertone to it. Hence, it should be categorized as off-topic. However, my answer on Quora might help regarding this question https://qr.ae/pGlNLL

Answer (score 2):

Burning crackers is an integral part of Diwali, the festival of lights. Crackers are burnt in each and every household and the festival is celebrated with a lot of dazzle and splendor. It is popular belief that burning of crackers marks the victory of good over evil and for attaining peace, prosperity, health and wealth.

It is true that fireworks was invented by the Chinese.However, burning of cracker has become an intergal part of Diwali celebration.Hence, I believe this can not become any off-topic just because there is not mention about them in scriptures.

It is believed that  Mughal emperor Akbar started organising mammoth firework displays during Diwali(This celebration is due to direct relation with Jodha Bai,as they she was allowed to follow her tradition and religion).

They called it **aatishbazi** or a grand show of fireworks. It is said that the fireworks display at Akbar’s capital Agra, could be seen from the Qutab Minar in Delhi as well.

[image]

*A Muslim and A Hindu lady in Diwali celebration(Notice the difference in their attires)*

Maybe The following link could provide more details about Mughal Diwali celebration.

http://www.thehindu.com/features/metroplus/down-memory-lane-blast-from-the-past/article6491805.ece

The earliest known Sanskrit text(16th century, possibly dated between 1497 and 1539,) to mention fireworks  is **Kautukacintamani**, by **Gajapati Prataparudradeva** of Orissa, contains a few Sanskrit verses on the ingredients needed to manufacture fireworks, including sulphur, charcoal, saltpetre, quicksilver, a hollow piece of bamboo and cow urine.

Before this text, in 1466, fireworks were said to be introduced in Kashmir, according to a Persian treatise on the manufacture of fireworks by Kashmiri king Zain-ul-Abidin, who reigned from 1421-1472.

Also a treatise from Karnataka dated after 1400 describing a form of fireworks for display for the king, and a text in Marathi from the early 1500s describing the use of fireworks in a wedding procession. Duarte Barbosa, a Portuguese voyager who traveled to India in 1518, made a reference to firecrackers in his own writing, where he described a Brahmin Gujarati wedding that included “firing of bombs and rockets in plenty, for their pleasure”.
These passage are extraction from a book titled '*A History of Fireworks in India'*, published in 1953 by PK Gode.

Evidently, the tradition of bursting firecrackers on Diwali day has been around for a 300 years or more, even if it may not have been a part of the festival in ancient times. Incorporating fireworks into the celebrations of Diwali make a symbolic sense.Famous mythologist Devdutt Pattnaik comments “Sound and light were traditionally meant to scare away misfortune.” In this sense celebrating Diwali with fireworks is not against the religion.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not please God and there is not any such mention in the scriptures. As you mentioned, the reason is rather historical because crackers were used to scare away wild animals in ancient times. This is not needed now and is just followed due to tradition. Sri Sri Ravi Shankar talks about it in this video:

https://www.facebook.com/SriSriRaviShankar/videos/10153445108937536/