# Why are crackers used on Diwali?

Tags: festivals

I don't know if this question is related on not. But why and how Diwali, a festival of lights turned into a festival of crackers? How this all started? 
Is there any relation of this festival with crackers from ancient times? Loud noise.... Is this tradition wrong or right?

Comment: Related [What is the reason behind use of crackers for temple festivals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11445/5212)

Comment: Crackers are nowhere mentioned to be burst. stupid people started making it a custom and now everyone thinks crackers are "**integral**" part of Deepavali. one of my teachers said- "Ban of crackers is wrong. How would coming generations know that we burst cracker on Diwali". And I thought- How ignorant people are.

Comment: When lord rama returned to ayodhya,there were no crackers at that time same is with christmas when jesus Christ was born there were no crackers at that time,it's just the way of celebrating festival and diwali is Also known as festival of lights.

Comment: It is a cultural phenomenon, not religious. Deepavali from a religious pov is about lighting oil lamps.